# How to Group Plug-ins into Features

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

We are struggeling hard with how to use features the correct way.

Let’s say we have the plug-in `org.acme.module` which depends on  `org.thirdparty.specific` and `org.acme.core`.

And we have the plug-in `org.acme.other` which depends on  `org.acme.core`.

We want to create an application from these, which includes a target file and a product file. We have the following options:

**One feature per module:**

- `org.acme.core.feature`

  - `org.acme.core`
- `org.acme.module.feature`

  - `org.acme.module`
- `org.acme.other.feature`

  - `org.acme.other`
- `org.thirdparty.specific.feature`

  - `org.thirdparty.specific`

This makes the target and product files gigantic, and the dependencies are very hard to manage manually.

**One feature per dependency group:**

- `org.acme.module.feature`

  - `org.acme.core`
  - `org.acme.module`
  - `org.thirdparty.specific`
- `org.acme.other.feature`

  - `org.acme.core`
  - `org.acme.other`

This approach makes the dependencies very easy to manage, and the target and product files are easy to read and maintain. However it does not work at all. The moment `org.acme.core` changes, you need to change ALL the features. Furthermore, the application has no say in what to package, so it can’t even decide to update `org.acme.core` (because of a bugfix or something).

**Platform Feature:**

- `org.acme.platform.feature`

  - `org.acme.core`
  - `org.acme.other`
  - `org.thirdparty.specific` (but could be its own feature)
- `org.acme.module.feature`

  - `org.acme.module`

This is the approach used for Hello World applications and Eclipse add-ons - and it only works for those. Since all modules' target platforms would point to `org.acme.platform.feature`, every time anything changes for any platform plug-in, you'd have to update `org.acme.platform.feature` accordingly.

We actually tried that approach with only about 50 platform plug-ins. It's not feasible to have a developer change the feature for every bugfix. (And while Tycho supports version "0.0.0", Eclipse does not, so it's another bag of problems to use that. Also, we need reproducibility, so having PDE choose versions willy-nilly is out of the question.)

Again it all comes down to "I can't use `org.acme.platform.feature` and override `org.acme.core`'s version for two weeks until the new feature gets released.

---

The entire problem is made even more difficult since sometimes more than one configuration of plug-ins are possible (let's say for different database providers), and then there are high level modules using other child modules to work correctly, which has to be managed somehow.

Is there something we are missing? How do other companies manage these problems?

The Eclipse guys seem to use the “one feature per module” approach. Not surprisingly, since it’s the only one that works. But they don’t use target platforms nor product files.

Comment: You've basically hit on the reason why Features don't work as an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The key to a successful grouping is when to use "includes" in features and when to just use dependencies. The difference is that "includes" are really included, i.e. p2 will install included bundles and/or included features all the time. That's the reason why you need to update a bundle in every feature if it's included. If you don't update it, you will end up with multiple versions in the install.

Also, in the old day one had to specify dependencies in features. These days, p2 will mostly figure out dependencies from the bundles. Thus, I would actually stop specifying dependencies in features but just includes. Think of features as a way to specify what gets aggregated.

Another key point to grouping is - less is more. If you have as many features as bundles chances a pretty high that you have a granularity issue. Instead, think about what would a user install separately. There is no need to have four features for things that a user would never install alone. Features should not be understood as a way of grouping development/project structures - that's where folders in SCM or different SCM repos are ok. Think of features as deployment structures.

With that approach, I would recommend a structure similar to the following example.

**my.product.base**

- base feature containing the bare minimum of the product
- could be org.acme.core plus a few minimum

**my.product.base.dependencies**

- features with 3rd party libraries for my.product.base

**my.addon.xyz**

- feature bundling an add-on
- separate features for things that can be installed separately

**my.addon.xyz.dependencies**

- 3rd party libraries for add-on dependencies

Now in the product definition I would list just my.product.base. There is no need to also list the dependencies features. p2 will fetch and install the dependencies automatically. However, if you want to bind your product to specific versions of the dependencies and don't want p2 to select any matching one, then you must include the my.product.base.dependencies feature.

In the target definition I would include a "my.product.sdk" feature. That feature is an aggregation feature of all other features. It makes target platform management easier. I typically create an sdk feature with everything.

Another feature that is also very often seen is a "master" feature. This is an "everything" feature that maybe used for creating a p2 repository during the build. The resulting p2 repository is then used for assembling products.

*For a more real world example see here:* 
http://git.eclipse.org/c/gyrex/gyrex-server.git/tree/releng/features

**Features and Continuous Delivery**

There was a comment regarding frequent updates to `feature.xml`. A `feature.xml` only needs to be modified when there is a change in structure. No updates need to happen when the bundle version is modified. You should reference bundles in features with version `0.0.0`. That makes Tycho to fill in the proper version at build time. Thus, all you need to do is commit a change to any bundle and then kick off a rebuild. Tycho also takes care of updating the feature qualifier based on the qualifiers of the contained bundles. Thus, the new feature qualifier will be different than in a previous build.

Comment: That's great for writing Eclipse addons, but doesn't work for real life products with multiple modules, where we also need the features for a [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Ftarget.htm). Just think about what happens if there's a bugfix in `org.acme.core` and you need a new version (possibly even a SNAPSHOT). You'd need to hire a monkey or something to update the feature hourly (since you can't "override" the version of a module defined in one feature, but have to build an entirely new one).

Comment: Steffi, please describe the issues you are running into. The original question was about feature structure. The problem raised in your comments is around versioning. That two different pairs of shoes. It's very easy to do continuous delivery with frequent updates to bundles. It actually works pretty nicely with snapshots. Leave the version in the feature.xml at 0.0.0 and Tycho will fill in the correct version at aggregation time. No need for any manual updates. Just commit change to a bundle and re-kick the build.

Comment: I tried to add to the question. It's not only about the structure, but about the build process as well. Having 0.0.0 as the version will kill the reproducibility, and always introduces a bunch of bugs (e.g. because developers stop maintaining _Manifest.MF_ files).

Comment: 0.0.0 will be used in the feature.xml. You can use ".qualifier" in the manifest.mf files but don't have to. You can continue to version manifests manually if you like. If you use ".qualifier" you can either generate them based from SCM information (such as last Git modification time) so that they are reproducible (search for Reproducible Version Qualifiers) - or you inject the qualifier from outside the build (such as build identifier). Then it's also reproducible and not random.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about the "0.0.0" in the target platform. Having no versions in the feature doesn't change anything. Something has to define versions (for us the target platform), so somebody has to update these versions so that the feature is up-to-date.

Comment: Oh, we also use 0.0.0 in target platforms successfully. There is no update to the target files necessary at all. However, due to caching, developers need to open their target platform regularly and refresh it. That will fetch the new bits. The feature version should only be updated when you begin a new development cycle. Features can also have qualifiers that increase with every build. Worked pretty well for us and we really only ever touched feature.xml and manifests at the begin of a new release cycle (and we have scripts for that).

Comment: The problem here is that the bundles in the base feature are in a different states in the development cycle. Some are just released (hence it's **wrong** to use a newer version), some are in the testing phase (0.0.0 is okay) and some are in development (the newest SNAPSHOT might even break the application, and the next release might still contain a lower version).

Comment: I don't see any issue with that. If a bundle source code is not modified (because it's in released state or a tasting phase) you can still reference it with 0.0.0 in the feature.xml assuming you have reproducible versions - which I assume you have because you stated that you want to manage it manually or use Tycho with SCM integration. Also, if a bundle is consumed as binary (from a released or testing repository) the version number will not change either.